# Regex to ignore capture start and end of sentence, but ignore the middle

Tags: regex

I have a regex that needs to capture the following strings:

`xxx 2018 12833833 19322222 KEY 83 a 84 a 1`

`2018 12833833 19322222 KEY Q 83 a 84 a 1`

`2018 12833833 19322222 KEY 0.5` --working fine

`2018 12833833 19322222 KEY C 9 83 a 84 a 1` --working fine

My regex is almost getting them all, but a few are failing, I am struggling with the inner part (`Q` on the middle one)

`(?P<YEAR>\d{4})\s(?P<EMPTY>[.\S]*)\s(?P<KAT>[A-Z\d]*)\s(?P<POP>[A-Z\s]*)\s(?P<REST>.*?)(?P<XXX>\s(?P<X1>\d*)\s(?:.{1})\s(?P<X2>\d*)\s(?:.{1})\s)?(?P<UNT>[0-9\.]*$)`

Here is what I am capturing wrong on each:
#1 and #2 - REST captures everything after POP, but last 1 (REST shouldnt capture anything)

I tried enforcing REST as optional with `?` but its capturing eitherway

Comment: Do you mean only in `2018 12833833 19322222 KEY Q 83 a 84 a 1` the group  `REST` should not capture anything? And the other groups that follow do? What is the logic to make that distinction? There are a lot of optional parts in the pattern, you can omit `{1}` and note that the `.` can also match a space.

Comment: I tried to make sense of what you are trying to do. Hopefully it is helpfull to you. See my [attempt](https://regex101.com/r/IhXARR/1)

Comment: @JvdV thanks, I think you got it right! I was not even close, please post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you may try:

```
(?P<YEAR>\d{4})\s(?P<EMPTY>\d{8})\s(?P<KAT>\d{8})\s(?P<POP>[A-Z]+(?:\s[A-Z]+)?)(?:\s(?P<REST>\d+))?(?:\s(?P<XXX>(?P<X1>\d+)\s.\s(?P<X2>\d+)\s.))?\s(?P<UNT>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

See the online demo over [here](https://regex101.com/r/IhXARR/1)

- `(?P<YEAR>\d{4})` - Named capture group of 4 digits.
- `\s` - Intermediate space characer.
- `(?P<EMPTY>\d{8})` - Named capture group of 8 digits.
- `\s` - Intermediate space characer.
- `(?P<KAT>\d{8})` - Named capture group of 8 digits.
- `\s` - Intermediate space characer.
- `(?P<POP>[A-Z]+(?:\s[A-Z]+)?)` - Optional named capture group whit at least 1+ uppercase alpha chars and an optional space with more uppercase chars.
- `(?:\s(?P<REST>\d+))?` - Optional non-capture group holding a named capture group of 1+ digits.
- `(?:\s(?P<XXX>(?P<X1>\d+)\s.\s(?P<X2>\d+)\s.))?` - Another optional non-capture group holding a named capture group with two nested named capture groups.
- `\s` - Intermediate space characer.
- `(?P<UNT>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Named capture group to catch 1+ digits with an optional decimal point followed by more digits.
- `$` - End string anchor.